# R problem - Mutate where max() and distinct() are true

Tags: r

I'm having some difficulty in producing a new feature for a given set of conditions.

Taking the 'iris' data set as a reproducible example I would like to find the maximum petal length for each species and create a new column, then assign the term 'highest_length' wherever the highest has been identified - I only want to display this on the row where this is applicable.

I'm missing something seemingly obvious to others but can't bridge the gap myself.  Would really welcome any pointers.

The code I've tried is as per below:

`iris%>% mutate(high_spec = case_when(distinct(Species) & max(Petal.Length) ~ 'high_length'))`

I get the following error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `high_spec`. ℹ `high_spec = case_when(distinct(Species) & max(Petal.Length) ~ "high_length")`. x no applicable method for 'distinct' applied to an object of class "factor"

I've tried changing species to a character vector but this did not work as intended either.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The LHS of `case_when` must be a logical expression. `max` returns the maximum *value*. `distinct` returns a `data.frame` (or `data.frame`-like) object. Can you include your expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure about the goal. Does this help: `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%  mutate(high_spec = ifelse(Petal.Length == max(Petal.Length),'high_length',NA))` ?

Comment: Thank you both, that's done the trick!  I was trying to use the wrong methodology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up from my comment above, I assume you are after something like this?

```r
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(high_spec = if_else(
        Petal.Length == max(Petal.Length), "high_length", "")) %>%
    ungroup()
```

There is no need here for `case_when`. Instead use `group_by` to perform an operation per `Species`.

If you do have multiple conditions, `case_when` may make sense; but in that case I recommend having a look at the examples given in `?case_when`. It's also always good practice with `case_when` to capture the fall through condition.